# Lock the Computer over Night and on Weekends

Tags: lock

Given my computer runs on Ubuntu, and I can install on it whatever I like: If I would want to prevent myself from using the computer in the night and on the weekend, what software solution comes closest to putting the computer into a box locked with a timer-lock?

Answer (score 1):

`pam_time` is the built-in way to restrict access based on time.  It can prevent logins, but existing sessions would continue.  Otherwise, people seem to script their own solutions.

**Links**

- [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)
- [Log on hours for users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423377/log-on-hours-for-users)
- [How can I allow access to SSH only at a specific time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366034/how-can-i-allow-access-to-ssh-only-at-a-specific-time/1366383#1366383)
- [How to lock yourself out of the primary account temporarily?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183530/how-to-lock-yourself-out-of-the-primary-account-temporarily)
- [how to restrict time used for using computer in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615989/how-to-restrict-time-used-for-using-computer-in-ubuntu)
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/pam_time.8.html